# Автоматическое изменение второго слайдера, при изменении первого слайдера | HTML+JS

Tags: javascript, html, слайдер

Имеется задача: у меня есть 3 слайдера, когда я начинаю изменять один слайдер, второй и третий слайдер обратно пропорционально автоматически начинают изменяться. Аналогично и с другими слайдерами. Т.е. при изменении одного слайдера, 2 остальных слайдера автоматически меняют свое значение обратно пропорционально изменяемому слайдеру. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте свой код к вопросу. Как пробовали это сделать вы?